# Next largest element in a binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm looking for a simple algorithm to find the next largest element (key) in a binary search tree, can anyone help?

Comment: 1)  How would you find the largest in a BST?  2)  What would you need to do to get to the second largest from there?

Comment: It depends on the representation you are using for the tree, and the invariants.  What are they?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Binary Search Tree Successor Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757082/java-binary-search-tree-successor-method)

Comment: @Berzerker - this is essentially the same question as the one you asked an hour ago.  We can't debug your code for you because you haven't shown us all of the code.  That is something you will have to (learn to) do for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "next largest," you mean, the next largest node from wherever the current node is...

From the current node, go right once.  You've gone to a higher valued node.  Then, go left as many times as possible.  You've ended at the lowest valued node which is still higher than where you started.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ray at cs.lmu.edu](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/images/bstexample.png))</sub>

Example.  Start at 60, go right once, go left as many times as you can.  You end up at 62.

Try the same thing for 41.  You will end up at 42.

EDIT:

This should help with your second case.  Pseudocode:

```
If (current.hasNoRightChild)
    testParent = current
    nextLargest = maxValueInTree
    While (testParent.hasParent)
        testParent = current.Parent
        If (testParent > current  && testParent < nextLargest)
            nextLargest = testParent
            While (testParent.hasLeftChild)
                testLeftChild = testParent.testLeftChild
                If (testLeftChild > current && testLeftChild < nextLargest)
                    nextLargest = testLeftChild
                End if
            End while
        End if
    End while
End if
```

Can't guarantee no bugs in that, but the general idea is you check each parent, slowly working your way to the top of the tree.  At each node, you stop and see if it is a candidate to be the "next largest" (i.e. it is greater than the node you started from and less than the current guess of next largest).  At each of these stops, if the node is greater than where you started, you must explore all the way down the subtree of that node on the left branch only, checking each value along the way.  I think that should do it, but you should probably test it heavily with random values to make sure there aren't any other cases we've overlooked.

Comment: that only works for the case if the element has a right child .

Comment: If there is no node to the right, then there is no greater node in the tree.  Maybe you need to more clearly define what you mean by "next largest element."  By your definition, what is the "next largest element" in the tree above?

Comment: for example, say you start at Node 55, you would need to traverse up until 41,(a node with left parent reference (60)) , then obtain and return the value of the node 60. I am having a problem with my implementation of exactly that in the above code.

Comment: Since you've reversed your acceptance of this answer, I assume you have an issue with it.  Could you please explain what that is?

Comment: @The111 This was such an intuitive answer...I should have seen that. Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: right (x) is non empty
successor (x ) = the minimum in right (x)
Case 2: right (x) is empty
go up the tree until the current node is a left child: successor (x ) is the parent of the current node
if you cannot go further (and you reached the root):    x is the largest element

Comment: When Parent pointer given-http://www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/view/8978432,when no parent pointer given-http://www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/view/9043968/find-next-higher-key-in-bst-ii-